# Reload Template after login and token store in localstorage

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have 2 templates in my VUE js HTML part. One is login and other one is home. The problem is how change template after login and token store in local storage.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <template v-if="condition">
            login part
        </template>
        <template v-else>else part</template>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Are you using vues router? I would say these sound like separate pages so I would use the router to navigate between the pages on login/logout

Comment: @LLai yes i'm using vue routes. but here i'm trying to use same template by using v-if and v-else conditional rendering. I just need when localstorage has not token it should show login page and when we enter correct credentials then we the template condition should again check and it should check localstorage that has user token and it should else part. that's all.

Comment: Use `<component :is=myComponent />` where `myComponent` is either a string or a Vue component. Move your condition in a computed.